# Is it possible to set up blog categories without changing permalink structure

Tags: categories, permalinks, blog

When our blog was initially set up, the permalink structure used was /blog/%postname%/  We've had it that way for about a year now and have good SEO results.  We want to create a press release category for the blog which should result in a permalink like /blog/press/%postname%/  But doing this breaks all of our SEO links.  I know that we can use a plugin to create 301s for the broken links... but I'm just wondering if there's another way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-posts/ try this one - I think this is should work for what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Thanks but it looks like that only allows me to create individual permalinks.  I'm not seeing a way with it to resolve anything at oursite.com/blog/press to a blog style page listing all posts with the press category.

Comment: Hi Geoff - sorry I misunderstood your question. I changed my answer with a plugin that should do what you are asking for. I believe you can use the shortcode to make just the posts from the category you want to display show up.